# She venerated her parents' memory

Tags: sentence-meaning

She venerated her parents' memory.

Is this sentence clear in its meaning?

whose memory is venerated?

her is possessive and parents' is also possessive.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=venerate+his+memory%2Ckeep+his+memory+alive&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) showing just how far the venerating of someone's memory has fallen into disuse over the past couple of centuries, to be supplanted by ***keeping their memory alive***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is perfectly clear in its meaning - as long as you're familiar with this use of *their memory*.

In English, we can chain possessives or attributions infinitely.  These are all valid and (reasonably) clear phrases:

*her car* - the car that belongs to her
*her parents' car* - the car that belongs to her parents
*her parents' friends' car* - the car that belongs to the friends of her parents
*her parents' friends' neighbors' car* - the car that belongs to the neighbors of the friends of her parents

In this case, *her parents' memory* means the memory of her parents.

The extra complexity in this phrase is that *their memory*, in this context, does **not** mean *the memory that belongs to them*.  This is a less common (but not uncommon) secondary meaning of *memory*:

> **memory** noun
>
> 2 a.  : commemorative remembrance
> // erected a statue in memory of the hero

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/memory

So, in a sense, we are talking about *her* memory of her parents.  But that's the semantics of the sentence.  Grammatically, the *memory* belongs to the parents, just like the car, in the example sentences.